# How do you install oDesk Team for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04

I am need of assistance on how to install oDesk Team (www.odesk.com/downloads) for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have tried downloading the 12.04 versions for Ubuntu but all I see in the status is Error: architecture error. Please Help.

Comment: An architecture error means that you're either installing 64bit onto 32bit or installing 32bit onto 64bit without having the 32bit libraries installed.

Answer (score 1):

To install oDesk Team,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

Next you need to install [libnotify1](http://pkgs.org/download/libnotify1)

Once installed, nedd to get oDesk software version. Go to the [oDesk Downloads page](https://www.odesk.com/downloads/os/linux), and download your desired version.  Once downloaded navigate to the download location (probably the Downloads folder), and then run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```

<sup>Source:kshatrea</sup>